# How to deal with the situation of server certificate over 16k?

Tags: ssl, certificate

As the title, when a server has a long list of certificates, supposed their total size is over 16KBytes, how to pack them into a TLSplaintext? If we can't, please tell me how to seperate the certificate chain into different TLSplaintexts?

I ask because in RFC 2246, the size of a 'Certificate' package could reach 2^24 bytes. That is over the maximum size allowed in a TLSPlaintext; 2^14+5 bytes. The standard does not mention how we can split the package when the size of a 'Certificate' package is over 2^14+5. That confuses me a lot.

Comment: Why would the server have such long list of certificates? Isn't there a server misconfiguration issue?

Comment: I'm just learning TLS 1.0 protocol and tring to implement a suite of API which have to understand how the server side deal with this situation. I did a lot of research online, nowhere has the exact answer.But it really happened. Many people mention this situation when their TLS client facing it.

Comment: What on earth is a 'TLS plaintext'? A contradiction in terms? Your question sounds like a re-implementation of something that TLS already does.

Comment: Are you talking about a 16K certificate chain, or a 16K list of CA's DNs (if you're requesting client-certificate authentication)?

Comment: To EJP: TLSPlaintext is a kind of packages in TLS 1.0 record layer. I do not try to make a new standard, I just try to implement a TLS LIB for study.

Comment: To Bruno: I mean a certificate chain in a certificate package, if this happens, what should I do? Seperate the chain into two certificate packages?

Comment: Really? Do you have a 16K certificate chain from the server cert itself to the root CA (or penultimate CA)? (Use @ to reply to a name, btw)

Comment: @Bruno, sorry, I don't have one. But I did search many people ask the solution online, such as this thread: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnutls/2012-05/msg00082.html.

Comment: Actually, I need a standard resolution for this. Because in the RFC 2246, the size of 'Certificate' package could be reached 2^24 bytes, it is over the maximum size, 2^14+5 bytes, allowed in a TLSPlaintext. The standard does not mention how we can split the package when the size of 'Certificate' package is over 2^14+5. And that confuses me a lot.